# Roads randomly segmented

Tags: arcmap, road

I've encountered a problem I'd like to fix. I have two shapefiles that are in essentially the same spot. (Road Centerlines)

We had a company run an analysis of the road quality. When they gave us the shapefile with the road ratings there were no street names, from, to, roads or anything else that would usefully link up their dataset to ours.

Additionally, their roads are somewhat randomly segmented. So instead of Main St from Smith to Jones being one block segment it could be 5 or 10. I haven't encountered anything over 20 though.

So from their dataset I need to pull a length weighted average rating. I need to grab Main St from Smith st to Jones st and take the length * rating of segments and then add all those values and then divide by the total length of that segment. Then I need to add it to our existing network. (I can add it to the network first if that's better).

My spatial join sort of worked but left out a lot of rating data. I tried to dissolve but ended up with a bunch of roads joining that shouldn't have joined.

We use Esri ArcMap 10.6; the consultant uses OpenStreetMap.

Edit: How do I join these two data sets? I’d prefer to “dissolve” the consultants road data to get the weighted average pavement score by block first then do a spatial join to our data.

Comment: "Essentially"?  If you run an intersect/union of both layers with an acceptable tolerance is all the information of both included in the new layer with no or very little stretches of either unmatched?  If there's a few you could manually fix that.  If so all the information would be in the combined layer.  At that point I'd probably export the table to a spreadsheet or database for analysis, and then create a table to join back to road shapefile.  Prior to export create a field for linking the data back.

Comment: If you have the shorter segments, then I don't see how their data can be at the block level. You'd have to get your data attributes associated with their ratings, then do processing. Or split their data to match your lengths, which sounds more difficult.

Comment: @danak Their data is the short segments already. The existing road network is already by block. Did I misunderstand what you’re trying to say?